# Как перенести слово в css?

Tags: css

есть таблица с колонками td, у td есть фиксированная ширина,когда добавляешь файл,то слово появляется в ячейке td(yj если слово длиное,то оно попросту не помещается в него и переходит на следующий td,как сделать чтобы длинное слово переносилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://htmlbook.ru/blog/perenosy-slov - тут подробно
Если кратко, то есть word-break: break-all;
но оно может переносить весьма странно

Comment: все,проблема решена!

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).